# 80s/90s Sci-fi/horror story where pregnant women couldn't deliver their children

Tags: story-identification, horror

Because of genetic changes, pregnant women can't naturally deliver their children. In one scene, a woman almost 9 months pregnant died in a public toilet. She got a serious pain in her abdomen, and then her intestines, guts and the fetus came out.

The main character was a doctor, I think. He have to find the way to help his wife from these terrified dead.

Does anyone know the name of this piece of fiction?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Is there anything else you can remember about this story - was it a novel or short story, was it in English, where was it set? You may be interested to read [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking story-ID questions.

Comment: "terrified dead"?

Comment: Oh! I think I know this.... Well, it’s *Darwin’s Radio*. But given that there’s another question with this as its answer, and that the poster of this one hasn’t come back....